# Using gradle for dependency managment

Tags: jsf, gradle, openfaces

I am trying to use gradle only for the jar dependencies, meaning that I took all the jars from the build path and wrote it like this:`compile 'groupid:artifactid:version'`.

Now when I am trying to run the server (tomcat 7.0.39) I get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Second notification for the same phase in the same request occurred. phaseId.ordinal: 1; phaseId = RESTORE_VIEW 1; More than one org.openfaces.component.validation.ValidatorPhaseListener is found to be registered (2). Check that only one JSF implementation is deployed with your application's classpath, and openfaces.jar is not duplicated in application's and server's libraries.
```

I don't understand what am I supposed to do and where to look.

Can someone shed some light?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to run `gradle dependencies` to view the dependency tree. Then search for the problematic packages - it should be doubled. You need to exclude one of the conflicting packages. [Here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:how_to_declare_your_dependencies)'re a docs on dependencies exclusion.

Comment: Great, glad that it helped you.